# How to use Powershell command invoke-sqlcmd in batch script

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, powershell

I have a Powershell command that I want to be run in a batch script. It works well in the Powershell console, but I cannot call it properly in batch script. The Powershell command goes like this:

```
invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile "D:\T3 Reports\sql.sql" -ServerInstance ISD-DB02 | export-csv "D:\T3RawDataFiles\T3HistoricalRaw\Complaint\samp.csv" -Force -En UTF8
```

Why doesn't this command work in a batch script?

Also, is it possible to use a batch variable in place of the file path for input and output file instead of putting the whole path in the Powershell command (still run inside in batch script)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that works :) to run the invoke-sqlcmd within batch script:

I have use this line:

```
powershell -Command "& {Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100; Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100; invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile '%sqlPath1%' -ServerInstance %Server% | export-csv '%out_path1%\%out1_fn%' -Force -En UTF8;}"
```

works like charm yay! ^_^

Comment: yup, that's the typical way to do it :-)